# D3 force layout from CSV with multiple edges per row

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a D3(v3) force layout from a CSV containing several edges per row:

```
"c.compound","mt.entry","mt.protein_names","tt.gene_name","tt.gene_product","omcl.omcl_clusterid"
"TCMDC-143527","A0A059UE90","Glycogen synthase kinase-3 beta splice variant X1","TcCLB.507993.80","glycogen synthase kinase 3, putative","OG5_126888"
"TCMDC-143376","A0A059UE90","Glycogen synthase kinase-3 beta splice variant X1","TcCLB.507993.80","glycogen synthase kinase 3, putative","OG5_126888"
"TCMDC-143527","A0A059UE90","Glycogen synthase kinase-3 beta splice variant X1","Tb427.10.13780","glycogen synthase kinase 3","OG5_126888"
"TCMDC-143376","A0A059UE90","Glycogen synthase kinase-3 beta splice variant X1","Tb427.10.13780","glycogen synthase kinase 3","OG5_126888"
...
```

I need this force layout to reflect the following edges:

```
c.compound -> mt.accession
mt.entry -> omcl.omcl_clusterid
tt.gene_name -> omcl.omcl_clusterid
```

I'm new to D3 so I started with a code example give by [mbostock](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2949937) on github. This example receives a CSV file, parses it row by row, and extracts A to B edges (one by row) from a CSV like the following

```
source, target
"A", "B"
"B", "C"
...
```

I thought I would be able to adapt the code in the example to my needs by doing an additional iteration each row and stashing all links in an array and then proceed normally... like this:

```
  d3.csv("allomcl_putative_test.csv", function(error, links) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nodesByName = {};
  var rels = [];
  // Create nodes for each unique source and target.
  links.forEach(function(link) {

      var compound = nodeByName(link["c.compound"]);
      var mt = nodeByName(link["mt.entry"]);
      var tt = nodeByName(link["tt.gene_name"]);
      var omcl = nodeByName(link["omcl.omcl_clusterid"]);

      rels.push({
          "source": compound.name,
          "target": mt.name
      });
      rels.push({
          "source": mt.name,
          "target": omcl.name
      });
      rels.push({
          "source": tt.name,
          "target": omcl.name
      });

  });

  rels.forEach(function(d) {

      link = {
          "source": d.source,
          "target": d.target
      };
  });

...
```

I've logged to console that both the links and the nodes are being collected properly, but I'm unable to start the force layout. Javascript console will prompt the following error:

```
TypeError: r.source is undefined[Learn More]
d3.v3.min.js:4:22668
ao.layout.force/l.start
https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:4:22668
<anonymous>
file:///root/to/my/file/test.js:74:7
Cn/u.send/<
https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:11277
t
https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:1563
i
https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:10130
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Edges cannot be sourcing or targeting strings (at least in D3 v3), so it is necessary to add create links passing indexes instead of names. In order to do so, I adapted the nodeByName function, first:

```
  function nodeByName(name) {
      return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {
          name: name,
          index: nodeid++
      });
  }
```

... with nodeid being a variable created before the csv parsing and autoincrementing itself with every node creation.

Then I changed the edge creation chunk of code to use these indexes:

```
  rows.forEach(function(link) {

      var compound = nodeByName(link["c.compound"]);
      var mt = nodeByName(link["mt.entry"], link["mt.protein_names"]);
      var tt = nodeByName(link["tt.gene_name"], link["tt.gene_product"]);
      var omcl = nodeByName(link["omcl.omcl_clusterid"]);          

      rels.push({
          "source": compound.index,
          "target": mt.index
      });
      rels.push({
          "source": mt.index,
          "target": omcl.index
      });
      rels.push({
          "source": tt.index,
          "target": omcl.index
      });

  });
```

It now works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, if you change to D3 v4 or v5 you can link by name.